# Dartium is expired

Tags: dart, dartium

Just today Dartium is reporting that it is expired and no combination of downloading and re-installing or rebooting or deleting and re-installing resolves the problem. The only solution I have found is to change the Date/Time of my server to yesterday. This is allowing me to function at the moment, but is obviously not a long term solution.

It almost appears to me that the elimination of Dartium as part of Dart2 means that new versions are not being created even though the binaries are expiring. Maybe? Dart2 is not yet considered "stable" and not all pub packages are ready, so it is a bigger job to upgrade than I have time for right now.

Thoughts or Suggestions?

Comment: A lot of people will be reading this today and looking for answers... and when i mean a lot of us, i mean the 10s of 10s of Dart Developers. I am hoping California wakes up soon in order to make an announcement.  If i get any info, Ill post it.

Answer (score 11):

You are not alone https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33580

To work around you can use this command to start Dartium

```
export DARTIUM_EXPIRATION_TIME=1577836800; ./chrome-wrapper
```

or just set the environment variable in your system

```
DARTIUM_EXPIRATION_TIME=1577836800
```

Comment: This is just a workaround and not a solution.  I like it so i +1, but it just a delaying action. :-/

Comment: I don't know what the plans are. Dart 1 isn't maintained anymore and Dart 2 doesn't include Dartium anymore. Perhaps the Dart team will release a final Dartium build that doesn't expire. Follow the linked issue for that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Sorry I didn't get back to my own post/question. If anyone from the Dart team is actually reading this, then I think Gunter's request is extremely reasonable.

Comment: One of the things Dartium is necessary for, is to run Angular Dart in Plunker, e.g. http://embed.plnkr.co/6Mxz6r/. Too bad Dartium is expired like this. Ability to run a quick an easy example is invaluable. I know one can setup something like https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/debugging to experiment with Angular Dart but that is so much effort for first time adopters.

Comment: Dartium can't run Dart 2 and older Angular versions are long discontinued. The Dart team is continually working on improving the experience. Dart 2 was a big step and is just out a few months. There is room for optimization but that will take a while.